# I want to add subview inide the swift playgounds liveview for testing constraint but fail to display , the inner view added was disappeared

Tags: swift, xcode

I want to add subview inide the swift playgounds liveview for testing constraint but fail to display , the inner view added was disappeared. it just draw in the quick look , but disappeared inside the liveview, how can i modify the position of the inner view with constaints ?

```
//: Playground - noun: a place where people can play

import UIKit
//import KeyBoardWubi
import PlaygroundSupport

var str = "Hello, playground"

var u1 : UIView

//u1 = KeyBoardWubi3(frame: CGRect(x: 20, y: 20, width: 200, height: 200))
//u1

var v1,v2,v3 : UIView

func addview(vin:UIView){
    var v4 : UIView
    v4 = UIView(frame : CGRect(x: 40, y: 40, width: 800, height: 100))
    v4.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    vin.addSubview(v4)
    v4.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    v4.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vin.leftAnchor, constant: 12.0).isActive = true
}

v1 = UIView(frame : CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: 200, height: 200))
v1.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = v1
addview(vin: v1)

v1
```

[image]

Comment: Deleting the line `v4.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo:...` seems to work...

Comment: Yes, but the v4 view position will be set to the default , i just want to modify the position of v4 inside the v1 .  how can i do that ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your auto-layout constraint is invalid. It only has the left anchor. Playground does not warn you about invalid constraints. If this were a real app, you'd have known.

Try this:

```
import UIKit
import PlaygroundSupport

func addview(vin:UIView){
    // Since you are using auto-layout, the initial frame is irrelevant
    let v4 = UIView(frame: .zero)
    v4.backgroundColor = .blue

    // Set this **before** adding v4 to another view
    v4.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false

    vin.addSubview(v4)

    // Playground doesn't warn you about invalid auto layout constraints
    // This is where you set the size and position of the new view
    v4.leftAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vin.leftAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
    v4.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: vin.topAnchor, constant: 40).isActive = true
    v4.widthAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 800).isActive = true
    v4.heightAnchor.constraint(equalToConstant: 100).isActive = true
}

let v1 = UIView(frame : CGRect(x: 0, y: 20, width: 200, height: 200))
v1.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
addview(vin: v1)
PlaygroundPage.current.liveView = v1
```